# Retrieve the database password with admin privileges via code

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

How can one obtain his/her database password with code while the admin privileges are proved to be sufficient by windows authentication?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. Any self-respecting database would never store the passwords in clear text. It would only store a hash of the password and compare the hash of the password you enter to this hash. If you have administrative privileges, you can reset this password to some new value though.